# jq - transform all keys recursively

Tags: json, key, jq, transform

Using jq, I'd like to uppercase the first letter over every property name, recursively. Seems like it should be simple to upper.

Example Input Json:

```
{
  "field1": "v1",
  "field2": {
    "subfield1": "sv1"
  },
  "field3": ["av1", "av2"]
}
```

Desired Output:

```
{
  "Field1": "v1",
  "Field2": {
    "Subfield1": "sv1"
  },
  "Field3": ["av1", "av2"]
}
```

Jumping through hoops, I managed to get it working, but only for the first level.

```
cat x.json | jq '([ [ . |  (keys[] as $key | ($key[0:1] | ascii_upcase) + $key[1:]) ], [.[]] ]) | transpose |  map( {(.[0]): (.[1])}) | add'
```

It seems like it should be easy and that I'm missing something basic/fundamental. Pretty much a noob to jq

Answer (score 3):

Use `walk` to recursively apply a function everywhere.

```
jq 'walk(if type == "object"
         then
             with_entries(.key |= (.[0:1] | ascii_upcase) + (.[1:]))
         else .
         end)' file.json
```